# Sorting array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c-strings

I am trying to sort an array of pointers, which are pointing to a character array of names. I can get the program to sort the first two names but not the rest. Also the names are part of a structure.

```
void sort( Class* ptrs[], int num_classes){
    bool swap=false;

    do
    {
        swap=false;
        for (int i=0; i<=num_classes-1; i++) {

            if (ptrs[i]->title[i]>ptrs[i+1]->title[i]) {
                Swap(&ptrs[i], &ptrs[i+1]);
                swap=true;
            }
        }
    }while(swap);
}

void Swap(Class** num1,Class** num2){

    Class* temp=*num1;
    *num1=*num2;
    *num2=temp;
}

struct Class{
    char title[MAX];
    int units;
    char grade;
};

int main(){
    int choice,num_classes=0;
    char class_selection[MAX];
    Class* ptrs[MAX];
    char* class_ptr[MAX];
    bool Continue=false;
    Class classes[MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        ptrs[i]=&classes[i];
    }


    cout<<" 1. Add new class"<<endl<<" 2. Edit an existing class"<<endl<<" 3. Display a class"<<endl<<" 4. List all classes"<<endl<<" 5. Display GPA"<<endl<<" 6. Delete all classes"<<endl<<" 7. Quit"<<endl<<"Enter selection number: ";

    cin>>choice;
    if (choice!=7) {
        Continue=true;
    }
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            add(ptrs,num_classes);
            num_classes++;
            break;

        case 2:
            edit(ptrs,num_classes);
            cin.ignore();
            break;
        case 3:
            sort(ptrs,num_classes);
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"Enter the name of the class to display: ";
            cin.getline(class_selection, MAX);
            for (int j =0; j<MAX; j++) {
                class_ptr[j]=&class_selection[j];
            }
            Bin_search(ptrs,num_classes,class_ptr);

            break;
        case 4:
            sort(ptrs,num_classes);
            display(ptrs,num_classes);
            break;
        case 5:
            //     display_GPA();
            break;
        case 6:
            //  delete_end();
            break;
    }
    if (choice == 7) {
        //  delete_end();
        //system('pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: add main() please and what/where is the error

Comment: Simplify your life even more by using `std::vector<Class>`.  You could use the `std::sort` function.

Comment: For a bubble sort, you should loop until the container is sorted, not by the number of items in the container.

Comment: ... Is this a homework problem ... (Only reason that comes to mind on why use bubble sort on arrays. ) Anyhow, follow Thomas's advice and use vector and sort.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to use a vector, and yes it is a homework problem.

Comment: You can learn in jiffy, just try. STL containers will make your life simpler

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that is at least add the definition of `Class` and `main()`.

Comment: I added both the structure definition and the part of main where the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

This code is comparing `i`-th character of corresponding titles, not the whole titles:

```
if (ptrs[i]->title[i]>ptrs[i+1]->title[i]) {
//                ^^^                 ^^^
```

Possible ways to solve:

1. Change this

   ```
   char title[MAX];
   ```

   to

   ```
   std::string title;
   ```

   And after that you'll be able to write

   ```
   if (ptrs[i]->title > ptrs[i+1]->title) {
   ```
2. Only if you can't use `std::string` for some reason, use `strcmp`:

   ```
   if (strcmp(ptrs[i]->title, ptrs[i+1]->title) > 0) {
   ```